# Ionic app works with both "ionic serve" and in ionic view, but not with "ionic build ios"

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, google-api, geolocation

My ionic app uses google api geolocation service and works fine when I run it using "ionic serve" and with Ionic View app. However, when I run "ionic build ios" and run the app on my ios device, the geolocation service does not work. 
I thought it was because location service was not on. I went to setting > Privacy > Location Service to allow location service however, I realized that the app I am working on is not listed there. (But there is ionic view app icon and the location service is allowed. I think that's why it works with ionic view app). Also I realized that the app is not even listed on setting.

How can I list ionic app ("ionic build ios") on setting in ios so that I can change permission for location service?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added the `cordova whitelist plugin` that allows communication from third party resources for your app? May be you are not allowed on phone to get data externally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I added the plugin and tried again but still I cannot find the app icon in setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need the [GeoLocation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/) plugin to get access of location services in your phone. Try adding it by

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

and then allow access to it when it start using its services in your phone. This way your app will be listed in the location service settings too.

Comment: Yes, adding the plugin, it is working now. Thank you so much for your help!