# Why this ionic app code does not work on device but works with ionic serve on the web?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I appreciate if anyone can help me to fix the problem with this. The result of the app is to show the lat and long when app is running on the device.

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <ti

    tle>Geo Location</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://mts0.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>


      </head>
      <body ng-app='starter'>
        This is GeoLocation App

        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function showlocation() {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
        }

        function callback(position) {
           document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
           document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
        }
        </script>


    <input type="button" value="Show Location"
        onclick="javascript:showlocation()" />   <br/>

    Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>       <br/>

    Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);


      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

This is style.css:

```
.scroll {
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try opening chrome developer tools, and look in console from some errors, and post here

Comment: It doesn't have any errors.

Comment: check your internet connection on your device and check weather you have allow you current location. in your browser it will work because of your wi-fi connection but it will not show you the occurate place but in device you can by using gps location on.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is an Android then...

Connect your device to your computer and go to `chrome://inspect/#devices`. There you can debug your Ionic app as a website and see what's causing the problem.

> To inspect the device you need to enable USB Debugging on your
>   device.

Comment: i had the same problem and removed a folder named `mosqui`, your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and adding geolocation plugin solved the problem for me.

[Ionic app works with both "ionic serve" and in ionic view, but not with "ionic build ios"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266216/ionic-app-works-with-both-ionic-serve-and-in-ionic-view-but-not-with-ionic-b)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

Allow location service on your device from setting.